# How to use arrays in routes with Angular?

Tags: angular

I thought using `getAll` with a `paramMap` could help with getting arrays from the URL but apparently not.

Am I using it wrong?

Here's an example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjrjz9

I navigate with this

```
this.router.navigate(['two', {
  id: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}]);
```

And then I get the values

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  const ids = params.getAll('id');
  console.log('ids', ids);
});
```

console.log says `['1,2,3,4,5']` but I expected it to be `[1,2,3,4,5]` or even `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`

I'm just trying to pass an array to a route and then get the array back at the destination.
Of course, I could just split the string but what's the point of having `getAll` in that case? :)

Comment: Could you please describe what you are trying to do, with enough detail that an alternative might be suggested, and also paste the relative code here in addition to your example?

Comment: @theMayer I added more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if use [`routerLink`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink).

But, it's not currently working with your approach.

A bug in Angular's git is already open at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19179 for the same. You can track this issue there.

Comment: Not the answer I was expecting but at least now I know why. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

The `getAll()` method returns duplicate parameters as an array.

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/?query=a&query=b&query=c
```

The value would be:

```
console.log(params.getAll('query')); // prints ["a","b","c"]
```

All query parameters in the HTTP specification are strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I want a real array, I have to use query parameters and not optional parameters?  
I don't mind having an array of strings as long as it's an array.

Comment: @MrVoodoo I think you can use parameters or query parameters. If you want `getAll()` to return an array, then you have to duplicate the `id` parameter multiple times like this `id=1&id=2&id=3`. It's up to you, but I would just use `split()` because it allows for shorter urls.

Comment: How would you navigate to such a route then? In my case optional parameters would be like `.navigate(['route', {id: [someArray]}])`

Comment: @MrVoodoo I don't think you can, because in that example `id` is a named parameter. You might be stuck splitting it, but I've always done multiple Ids as a query parameter. There isn't a rule that says you have to, but generally I find it's mostly used in the context of a query. It's really just URL semantics.